# Calling particular child method from abstract class using custom annotation

Tags: java, annotations, abstract-class

I have a abstract class containing run() method and few children classes overriding run method with different implementation. There a custom annotation class also, each child class has this annotation with different value to distinguish each child class. I was to call this run method for each child class from abstract class object using these annotations without using child class name. Is it possible or there some other way to do this?

CODE IS HERE-------

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface CustomAnno {
    public String name();
}

public abstract class AbstractClass {

    abstract void run();

}

@CustomAnno(name="one")
public class ExtendingClassOne extends AbstractClass {

    @Override
    void run() {
        System.out.println("class one extending");

    }

}

@CustomAnno(name="two")
public class ExtendingClassTwo extends AbstractClass {

    @Override
    void run() {
        System.out.println("class two extending");

    }

}
```

So having abstract class and annotation values "one" and "two", can I call run method for each child class without using child class name.

Comment: I did not understand your question completely. But do you expect something like this?  `AbstractClass child1 = \\instance of ExtendingClassOne;  child1.run(); AbstractClass child2 = \\instance of ExtendingClassTwo; child2.run();` Can you provide some example?

Comment: Thanks for your reply dude. Here for calling run method of child class we have to initialise with its Object. I want to call child class using annotations and Abstract class only. Something like, we could load all annotations with their child classes at runtime. Did you get it now?

Comment: Yeah. I can understand.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider` spring library to list all the classes that use a particular kind of annotation. Here annotations can be custom or default one. So putting annotations on all child classes that extend that abstract class can give list of only those child classes only. This solved my problem.